# Recursion with loop inside

Tags: algorithms, time-complexity, asymptotics

What is the time complexity of this algorithm? I assume that is $O(3^n)$

```
n=3
recLoop(int n)
{
    for(int i=0; i<3; i++)
    {
        if(n>0)
        {
             recLoop(n-1); 
        }
        count++;
    }   
}
```

---

n 0 1 2 3 4

---

count 3 9 27 81 243

From this, I get $O(3^{n+1})$

If I change my algorithm to:

```
recLoop(int n)
{
    for(int i=0; i<3; i++)
    {
        for(int j=0; j<2; j++)
        {
            count++;
        }
    }
    for(int i=0; i<3; i++)
    {
        if(n>0)
        {
            recLoop(n-1);
        }
        else
            count++;
    }
}
```

From first nested loops $O(nm)$ so what is the total complexity of this algorithm?

---

n 0 1 2 3 4

---

count 9 33 105 321 969

The possible solution is a bit hard for me to understand and to translate my problem. I need a bit more description of my problem.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Is there a system behind the magic of algorithm analysis?](https://cs.stackexchange.com/questions/23593/is-there-a-system-behind-the-magic-of-algorithm-analysis)

Comment: @DavidRicherby it is a bit hard for me to translate my algorithm into a mathematical expression. If you think that that answer can solve my problem can you please explain to me how I can solve mine.

Comment: Let $T(n)$ be the cost of running `recloop(n)`, expresss that in terms of $T(n-1), \dots, T(0)$ and attempt to solve the recurrence.

Comment: @DavidRicherby For the ```recloop(n)``` I know the $T(n) = nc$, but adding the for loop before the recurrence I don't know how to solve it.

Comment: The question I linked to explains how to write the recurrence in terms of what the code is doing. $T(n)=nc$ isn't a recurrence: it's a statement that`recloop(n)` takes time linear in $n$, which doesn't take into account the recursive calls.